# Compare String, Count String which is equal and Store the equal strings count

Tags: string

```
public class Mic extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected static final int RESULT_SPEECH = 1000;
    private ImageButton btnspeak;
    private TextView tvText,tvText1;
    Button button4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mic);

        tvText1 = findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        tvText = findViewById(R.id.tvText);
        btnspeak = findViewById(R.id.btnspeak);
        btnspeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "Hi Speak Something");
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
                    tvText.setText("");
                    if(!tvText1.getText().toString().isEmpty()|| !tvText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                        String s1 = tvText1.getText().toString();
                        char[] array = s1.toCharArray();
                        int[] x = new int[s1.length()];
                        String s2 = tvText.getText().toString();
                        char[] array1 = s2.toCharArray();
                        int[] y = new int[s2.length()];
                        int equals=0;
                        for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++)
                        {
                            for(int j=0;j<s1.length();j++)
                            {
                                if(Objects.equals(s1[i],s2[j])) {
                                    equals++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        int diff=s1.length()-equals;
                        System.out.print(diff);
                    }
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your device doesn't support speech to text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RESULT_SPEECH:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null!=data) {
                    ArrayList<String> text = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    tvText.setText(text.get(0));
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Java Code, I have an Textview of tvText1, EditTextView of tvText and a image. I am trying to get the voice to text. This should compare the text and it should give the count of the String which is similar to both the String. Please help me with this problem.